# Using ggplot to plot multiple lines along the x-axis, coloured by their group but remaining seperate

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to use ggplot to create a line graph, with the values of each 'Molecule' represented by a different line. I want to use 'Family' to colour each line. I am having issues with this and can't seem to represent the individual values as separate lines, nor colour them based on their family.

```
df.long = melt(df, id.vars = c("Molecule", "Family"), measure.vars = c(3:7))
ggplot(df.long, aes(variable, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = Molecule)
```

I end up plotting something like this:

[image]

If someone could help me work this out, I would appreciate it.

This is how my data is organized, in wide format:

| Molecule | Family | Pos1 | Pos2 | Pos3 | Pos4 | Pos5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | i | 2.178 | 1.289 | 0.656 | 0.956 | 0.711 |
| B | ii | 1.478 | 0.889 | 0.578 | 0.689 | 0.444 |
| C | ii | 1.389 | 1.078 | 1.189 | 0.944 | 1.844 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get separate lines for each `Molecule` you have to map `Molecule` on the `group` aes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- read.table(text = "Molecule   Family  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5
A   i   2.178   1.289   0.656   0.956   0.711
B   ii  1.478   0.889   0.578   0.689   0.444
C   ii  1.389   1.078   1.189   0.944   1.844", header = TRUE)

df.long = melt(df, id.vars = c("Molecule", "Family"), measure.vars = c(3:7))
ggplot(df.long, aes(variable, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = Family, group = Molecule))
```

[image]

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much. What a great fix!
Edit: Solved the problem

Comment: (: BTW: The reason why we need the `group` aes is that your x `variable` is itself a categorical variable. In that case ggplot2 by default uses the variable mapped on `x` for the grouping, that's why you get the vertical lines.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So many methods to learn! Much appreciated